# How to insert an XML file into a column

Tags: c#, postgresql

I'm trying to upload a user profile settings xml(as a whole file into a column of xml data type) into my postgres database using c# , here is my code,

```
var connstring = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["pgcon"].ConnectionString;

using (NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connstring))
{
    conn.Open();

    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.Load("G:\\new repo\\setting xmls\\settings.xml");
    //workinq query insert
    //  string sql2 = string.Format(@"INSERT INTO Public.""UserDetails"" (id, usercode, address) VALUES ('dd', 'code', '1001')");

    NpgsqlCommand dbcmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    try
    {                       
        string sql = string.Format("SET SEARCH_PATH to Public;");                          
        string sql0 = string.Format(@"INSERT INTO Public.""UserProfile"" (setting, userstatus, userstatusdescription, id) VALUES ('{0}', true, 'active', 'ddd');", xmlDoc);

        dbcmd.CommandText = sql + sql0;
        dbcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

But , it is uploading as `System.Xml.XmlDocument` in the table , I need save it as an xml .

[image]
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try `string myXml = XDocument.Load("G:\\new repo\\setting xmls\\settings.xml").ToString()`

Comment: thanks much , its working fine . But one more issue , if my xml has single quote in some tags , it again failing. like this <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>

Comment: Glad I could help. I will put it down as an answer so it helps future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you can do the following

```
string myXml = XDocument.Load("G:\\new repo\\setting xmls\\settings.xml").ToString()
```

Then

```
string sql0 = string.Format(@"INSERT INTO Public.""UserProfile"" (setting, userstatus, userstatusdescription, id) VALUES ('{0}', true, 'active', 'ddd');", myXml);
```

Please use @ahammadalipk [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50838001/3793448) as this was originally posted to solve the XML upload issue the OP was having. @ahammadalipk answer covers the issue which the OP had with Sql Injection

Comment: LITTLE BOBBY TABLES!

Comment: @UweKeim care to explain

Comment: yes , having that issue , if we have single quote in xml , it might assume that our sql query is ended . http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: could you please explain how to avoid that ?

Comment: Can you provide a small snippet of your XML doc please

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
  <book id="bk101">
    <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
    <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
    <genre>Computer</genre>
    <price>44.95</price>
    <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
    <description>
      An in-depth look at creating applications
      with XML.
    </description>
  </book>
  </catalog>

Comment: I have fixed the issue by adding using NpgsqlParameter class , I think this will eliminate LITTLE BOBBY TABLES!  issue , can I post an answer ?

Comment: @AhammadaliPK That what I was working on and your answer will be correct so you can mark mine as unaccepted and I will delete it, my apologies for the confusion

Comment: No , your answer is relevant to the question . I'm able to upload the xml. When it comes to data with single quote it makes an issue

Comment: As you insist, happy coding. Definitely post your answer too though

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the issue **LITTLE BOBBY TABLES!**(making error when xml data contains single quotes and injection error), instead of adding parameters directly in the query , you can use `NpgsqlParameter` class.

instead of this ,

```
string sql0 = string.Format(@"INSERT INTO Public.""UserProfile"" (setting, userstatus, userstatusdescription, id) VALUES ('{0}', true, 'active', 'ddd');", myXml);
```

do this ,

```
NpgsqlParameter p = new NpgsqlParameter("@myXml", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Xml);
                    p.Value = myXml;
```

complete code ,

```
 using (NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connstring))
            {
                conn.Open();    
                string myXml = XDocument.Load("G:\\new repo\\setting xmls\\settings.xml").ToString();                     
                NpgsqlCommand dbcmd = conn.CreateCommand();
                try
                {

                    string sql = string.Format("SET SEARCH_PATH to Public;");                     
                    string sql0 = string.Format(@"INSERT INTO Public.""UserProfile"" (setting, userstatus, userstatusdescription, id) VALUES (@myXml, true, 'active', 'ddd');");                    
                    dbcmd.CommandText = sql + sql0;
                    NpgsqlParameter p = new NpgsqlParameter("@myXml", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Xml);
                    p.Value = myXml;                   
                    dbcmd.Parameters.Add(p);
                    dbcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    throw;
                }



            }
```

Happy coding! for the late comers .